# How to get a value of the return only?

Tags: c++

How to get the value that is returned from a function without running the function again?

For example:

```cpp
int difficulty() {
    char x;
    while (true) {
        if (kbhit()) {
            x = getch();
            if (x == '1' || x == '2' || x == '3') {
                return x;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "done";
}
```

This function is called in:

```
void Move(){
    if (HeadY >= Height-1 || HeadY <= 0 || HeadX >= Widht-1 || HeadX <= 0)
        Lose = false;
    char level=diffculty(); //**********
    if(level=='2' || level=='3'){
        for(int i=0;i<Ta_N;i++)
            if(HeadX==Ta_X[i] && HeadY==Ta_Y[i])
                Lose = false;
    }
}
```

And called in the menu function:

```
void menu(){
    if(kbhit()){
        x=getch();
        if(x=='s' || x=='S'){
            system("cls");
            table();
            while(Lose){
                Line();
                Input();
                Move(); //***********
                Sleep(50);
            }
            system("pause");
        }
    }
```

I need the `x` value only to compare it, but it runs the code again??

Comment: Save the return value in a variable `int xx = difficulty();`. Then whenever you later need the return value, just use the variable `xx`.

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate on what you mean by 'run the code again'? I'm not sure what you mean there. When evaluating `x`, it surely does not re-run `getch()`.

Comment: @lorro i put this code in for loop so it run it again

Comment: Note, unless you specifically need `getch()`, be aware that including `conio.h` makes your code 100% non-portable to anything but windows.

Comment: @kimo_liz Move it out of the loop then. If you don't want something to happen multiple times, don't put it in a loop. Without more context it's hard to give more specific advice.

Comment: @john i did but the varible is saved in a for loop

Comment: @kimo_liz Post how you are using the function as well then

Comment: ***i did but the varible is saved in a for loop*** Please then show the code you have a problem with. You showed the working part of the code and did not show the code that you need fixed.

Comment: @kimo_liz Unfortunately I didn't realise that you were using a loop. It's hard to answer questions helpfully when there is so little context. There's no magic way to stop functions being called again. The right way depends on exactly what you are trying to do. Information we don't currently have.

Comment: Modify the second line like this: `char x = getch()`
Then eliminate the 5th line `x = getch()`.
This works if `getch()` does not depend from calling `kbhit()`.

Comment: That `break` is not achieving much.

Comment: `int difficulty()` should probably be `char difficulty()` if you return a `char` and expect a `char`

Comment: @drescherjm i tried so

Comment: You probably need to use a debugger to debug your code line by line looking at the variables and flow at each line. Although there are things we can point out like the `break` after the return that does nothing it's difficult to see a real problem.

Comment: You should perform keyboard input in one place, ie at the top of your main loop, and then save, or pass around, any pressed keys for any functions that want them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want to create `x` in `menu()` and then store it as a variable to pass down the chain of function calls started in `menu()`.

Under this assumption what you ought to do is simple. `menu()` becomes:

```
void menu(){
    if(kbhit()){
        char x=getch();   // CHANGED
        if(x=='s' || x=='S'){
            system("cls");
            table();
            while(Lose){
                Line();
                Input();
                Move(x);   //CHANGED
                Sleep(50);
            }
            system("pause");            
       }
   }
}
```

Then `Move()` should be modified into `Move(char x)`:

```
void Move(char x){   // CHANGED
    if (HeadY >= Height-1 || HeadY <= 0 || HeadX >= Widht-1 || HeadX <= 0)
        Lose = false;
    char level = difficulty(x);   // CHANGED
    if (level=='2' || level=='3'){
        for (int i=0;i<Ta_N;i++)
            if (HeadX==Ta_X[i] && HeadY==Ta_Y[i])
                Lose = false;
    }
}
```

`difficulty()` becomes `difficulty(char x)`

```
char difficulty(char x) {   //CHANGED 
    // DELETED LINE char x;
    // REDUNDANT AS EXPLAINED IN COMMENT BELOW while (true) {
    // REDUNDANT    if (kbhit()) {
            // DELETED LINE x = getch();
    if (x == '1' || x == '2' || x == '3') {
        return x;
                // DELETE THIS break;
    } else
        throw("what happens when x != 1 or 2 or 3?");   //ADDED
    // REDUNDANT   } else
    // REDUNDANT        throw("what happens when kbhit() is false?");   
    // REDUNDANT }
    cout << "done";
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing `x` around by reference? The functions are not modifying it, so passing a reference is not needed. Just pass the value instead. Also, since you are changing things, the `while` and `kbhit()` wouldn't belong in `difficulty()` anymore since that is now handed by `menu()`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Apparently `x` is not modified, but who knows if `kbhit()` has any side effect? So just to stay safe I chose to pass `x` by reference.

Comment: And how do you expect `kbhit()` to have side effects on `x`? It doesn't, and it can't. So no, there is no need to pass `x` by reference at all in this example.

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer, and my comments were before your edits